# Is it possible to create an Android application directly on the HTC Evo phone?

Tags: android, htc-android

As a means of simplifying development, I'd like to be able to create and test an application right on my handset.

Is it possible to build an application directly on the HTC Evo phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry. With the Android Scripting Environment, you can write small scripts that run on the device. But the build tools require a fair bit more memory and computing power than an Android phone offers.

Comment: That is what I suspected ... had to make sure though cause it would have been cool.

Answer (score 1):

There is now an app out for this: [AIDE - Android IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui) (download it from Google Play).

It's a development environment for Java and C++ that runs on Android.